# How to add TITLE and ALT to an background image (CSS Sprites)?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

In my project I had used CSS sprites as there was lots of images,now our SEO team was saying that images should have `ALT` and `TITLE` tag. I know `Title` & `ALT` can't be added on the background. So they come up with an idea that put an transparent image in html over those images in background, but it seems very illogical to me(If the image is not relevant with the keyword, then how does it matter). So please help me with this, what is the best practice for this with very logical reason in support of your answer? so I can handle the SEO team.

Comment: Apparently your SEO team doesn't know the difference between images that are part of content, and background images meant for decoration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say do not use transparent images since earlier versions of IE do not support them nicely. You will see black blocks. But this is avoidable with some javascript hacks.

If they are just background images that don't add to the meaning of the site, keep it as just a background image, but if the image adds meaning to the site you should really use img tags and use alt tags as they suggest. Alt tags help with SEO.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. its very much logical
tell me one thing, which out of these has higher rating in SEO, Text in alt tag or a real text (if i put real text with text-indent)

Comment: Search engines look for the alt tag and award points for accessibility and having related images on the page. Using text indent would just add text to your page, kind of deleting an SEO advantage of using alt tags and explaining to search engines that you are ALSO using images related to the content.

Comment: don't worry.. you will surely get it xD